# Obtener MAC en Django/python de un Dispositivo que accede a determinada URL

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

Quiero obtener la mac de un dispositivo cuando en el dispositivo se ejecuta o accede a la URL: 127.0.0.1/Respuesta,
la cual esta definida en URLs como: url(r'^respuesta$', app.views.respuestaViewiew, name='Respuesta'),

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

def respuestaView(request):
    mac = get_mac()
        mac = ':'.join(("%012X" % mac)[i:i+2] for i in range(0, 12, 2))
```

mac me retorna la MAC del dispositivo en donde esta corriendo la aplicación PERO no la mac del dispositivo
que accedio a la URL:127.0.0.1/Respuesta

Answer (score 0):

No. Eso que estás tratando de hacer, no se puede. Punto.

La única alternativa es que el dispositivo que origina la llamada *HTTP* te lo pase explícitamente en algún parámetro.

Este es el NETWORK STACK simplificado:

```
CAPA APLICACIÓN (HTTP)
CAPA TCP
CAPA IP <--------------- OJO CON ESTA CAPA
CAPA DE ENLACE (MAC)
CAPA FÍSICA
```

En una aplicación WEB, puedes ir hasta la capa IP, pero no más abajo.

Cuando tu paquete salió de tu *LAN* y entró a la CAPA IP, (es decir cuando algún ruter dirigió tu paquete a otras redes) la información del `MAC ADDRESS` original se pierde para siempre.

Comment: Te refieres a que le pase directamente la MAC del dispositivo? si es asi como hago saber que es una MAC; con from uuid import getnode as get_mac obtengo la mac, pero en este caso declaro dir_mac por asi decirlo: dir_mac='0A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F'